# Get-ADUser -SearchBase

Tags: powershell, script, active-directory, domain

Trying to run this script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Department,DC=Company,DC=COM" -Properties employeeID,displayName,surname,givenname,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,title,department,company,memberof
```

When the script runs it grabs everything under `OU=Department` but how can I get it to just grab user objects under `Department` > `Users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use the `-SearchScope` parameter and pass it the `OneLevel` argument to tell the command to not traverse per the default `SubTree` value it takes if you do not specify any `-SearchScope` parameter and value.

So just include: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel <Rest of your command>`

**Example PowerShell**

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Department,DC=Company,DC=COM"
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties employeeID,displayName,surname,givenname,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,title,department,company,memberof
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Get-ADUser -SearchBase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

  > > ### `-SearchBase`
  > >
  > > When the value of the ***SearchBase*** parameter is set to an empty string
  > >     and you are connected to a GC port, all partitions will be searched.
  > >
  > > <sub>[source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)</sub>
- [Get-ADUser](https://ss64.com/ps/get-aduser.html)

  > ```
  > -SearchScope
  >   The scope of an AD search.
  >   Possible values for this parameter are:
  >   Base or 0        Search only the current path or object.
  >   OneLevel or 1    Search the immediate children
  >   Subtree or 2     Search the current path/object and all children
  > ```
  >
  > <sub>[source](https://ss64.com/ps/get-aduser.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put another OU follwing Parent OU, in your case "OU=Department,OU=User,DC=Company,DC=COM"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Department,OU=User,DC=Company,DC=COM" -Properties employeeID,displayName,surname,givenname,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,title,department,company,memberof